# ReactJS isomorphic application and system server time

Tags: javascript, datetime, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I'd like to know what is the good practice to output `system` (server-side) based date/time in isomorphic `React` applications. There are a lot of ways really (ajax, environment verifications etc.), but the question is about true-way practice for that.

**For example:** the goal is to output current year in footer for trade mark.

**FYI:** I'm using `react-router` module, so rendering looks like that:
`ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />)`

**UPDATE:**
If I'm trying to use `Route` props like that:

```
match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
   //...
   if (renderProps) {
      renderProps.params.year = (new Date).getFullYear();
      res.status(200).send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />));
   }
   //...
});
```

and inside jsx:

```
<Footer year={ this.props.params.year } />
```

but following error appears:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: You're trying to render a
>   component to the document using server rendering but the checksum was
>   invalid. This usually means you rendered a different component type or
>   props on the client from the one on the server, or your render()
>   methods are impure.

Your help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to separate my React top-level component onto 2 parts: static markup and `React` rendered string.

Unfortunately due to `React Invariant Violation` it's impossible to have any data rendered differently, so component types and even props should be rendered in the **same** way.

Now it's possible to include any server-side unique content to the page (paste directly into static markup using any template engine).

Answer (score 0):

You may get the server time header via AJAX request:

```
getServerTime(){
    var xmlHttp;
    try {
        //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (err1) {
        //IE
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err2) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch (eerr3) {
                //AJAX not supported, use CPU time.
                alert("AJAX not supported");
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    xmlHttp.send('');
    return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
}
```

And get the year that way:

```
new Date(this.getServerTime()).getFullYear()
```

NOTE:
I assume that:

1. Your server responds to AJAX requests with correct header.
2. You render inside a class. Otherwise just add `functon` in front of the method and remove `this.` when you call `getServerTime().`

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: The author since updated his question and this response is no longer valid.**

---

Pretty much it's very simple, Date object is available on every browser and nodejs

```
render() {
  return <footer>{new Date().getUTCFullYear()} [c] MyCompany Inc.</footer>
}
```

If you want server-side date then

```
class Footer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <footer>{this.props.date} [c] MyCompany Inc.</footer>
  }
}

ReactDOM.renderToString(<Footer date={new Date().getUTCFullYear()} />);
```

Comment: No. As soon as it's rendered, browser date will be rendered. I need server-side date.

Comment: @OlegMeleshko then you should specify that in your question. Your question says nothing about a server. Server =/= System.

Comment: @OlegMeleshko isomorphic does not mean server-side

Comment: @OlegMeleshko Isomorphic means able to run on server and client. If you want to guarantee that the date comes from the server, then you should not implement an isomorphic solution, but rather a server-side solution.

Comment: Updated the question.